# How to [Authorize] attribute work for authorization with owin token?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-mvc-5.2

How to authorize attribute check token is valid or not?

```
public class TestController : ApiController  
{  
    [HttpPost]  
    [Authorize]  
    public string TestMethod()  
    {  
        return "This is testing for authorization working flow...";  
    }  
}

If token not valid then return 
{
Message:"token is expired"
}
```

Comment: The question does not make any sense. Please specify the problem give some background.

Comment: You have to create an Authorization Filter for that. Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841313/return-error-on-invalid-or-expired-token

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Return error on invalid or expired token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841313/return-error-on-invalid-or-expired-token)